# Radio Button Unselected Color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I have 2 radio buttons, where one is selected and the other isn't selected, one of them would be the active color, while the other is grey, so is there any way to change the unselected color from grey to white?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, you have to change the `ThemeData` of the container of your Radio buttons.

Assuming that you are using a `Row` Container:

```
  Theme(
        data: ThemeData.dark(), //set the dark theme or write your own theme
                  child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              //your attributes here...
            ),
            Radio(
              //your attributes here...
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

How it works?

Because if you check the code of the `ThemeData`, you'll see this validation

```
unselectedWidgetColor ??= isDark ? Colors.white70 : Colors.black54;
```

then dark theme is using white70

Answer (score 28):

Set `unselectedWidgetColor` prop of theme in `MaterialApp` like below:

```
return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'xyz',
      home: xyz(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        unselectedWidgetColor:Colors.white
      ),
    );
```

A useful tip that read the source code of radio.dart and you will get everything!

Comment: this help me 
if you need change all over application the you go to main.dart and  add `unselectedWidgetColor:Colors.white` in ThemeData it will effected on all application.

Comment: yeah, that's right! Radio.dart get the unselectedWidgetColor directly from theme.unselectedWidgetColor

Answer (score 8):

In case you want only to change Border Color for Widget when it's unselected

Just Customize **Fill Color** property

```
Radio(
            //here -----
            fillColor:  
            MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                return (isSelected)
                    ? CustomColors.green
                    : CustomColors.greyMedium;
              }),
            // ----

              value: 'en',
              groupValue: langValue,
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your **Radio** Widgets with **Theme** widget and add theme data with **unselectedWidgetColor** as color you want

Ex:

```
              Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(
                    //here change to your color 
                    unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.White,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                           Radio(), 
                           Radio()
                    ],
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    return Colors.white;
}

Radio(value: 1,groupValue: numTypeRadio,onChanged: onChangeRadio,fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

For global setting: Setting for an unselected color can be set in the theme with unselectedWidgetColor. However, using fillColor in RadioThemeData affects unselectedWidgetColor. The best practice is to use unselectedWidgetColor in theme and activeColor in the custom widget.